# Http Batch Operations for Spring Framework

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc

does anybody know if spring has a way to implement http batch operations, e.g. like in OData?

http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/batch-processing/

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring doesn't support HTTP batch requests out of the box (neither do other general purpose Java frameworks), so I started working on my own (still in beta stage): https://github.com/bedrin/batchy

[Apache Olingo](https://olingo.apache.org/) supports OData 4.0 and batch requests, so if OData is what you need, try Olingo.